Breaking down 岬波の英語の音読女子が載せてバズったやつ
I have difficulty trying to make sense of the dialogue below:

(The one with blond hair is 天神岬波.)
There is one sentence I am uncertain:

岬波の英語の音読女子が載せてバズったやつ

It is hard to make sense of the structure without particles. I think it is understood as "girls posted a clip that shows Minami's reading aloud in English class to [some social media site] and it was trending." I can't tell whether やつ is a thing or a person.
Also, in the previous sentence「出たwwあれだろ?」, I wonder whether this あれ refers to 岬波の英語の音読女子が載せてバズったやつ.

I would read it as 岬波の英語の音読を女子が載せてバズったやつ.

@weeab00 I somehow didn't notice the possibility aguijonazo suggested, but does it sound plausible to you? While he's clearly good at sports, is he also the kind of character who would go viral just for reading texts aloud in an English class?

Yes, it kind of makes sense. I am not sure whether he is that kind of character but he is kind of a guy who is good at everything from academics, sports, looks, etc.

@weeab00 Thanks, then aguijonazo is probably correct. Please read my edit.

EDIT:
Based on the discussion in the comment section, a more likely interpretation would be as follows. I somehow didn't notice this interpretation because I recognized him only as a good sport player.

岬波の英語の音読(を)、女子が載せてバズったやつ。
that stuff (=video) that went viral after a girl posted Minami's English pronunciation


(Original post)
I think "岬波の" and "英語の音読女子が載せてバズった" are two independent modifiers that modify やつ. あれ and やつ ("stuff") both refer to a video on an SNS.
英語の音読女子 is a little confusing expression, but I suppose there is a girl recognized with such a name. There seems to be no real person widely known as 音読女子, but I imagine it refers to a girl who went viral for pronouncing English in a special way, similar to how ダンス女子 can refer to a girl known for dancing.

岬波のやつ
That stuff of Minami's
英語の音読女子が載せてバズったやつ
That stuff which the English Read-aloud Girl posted and then went viral

And the combined meaning is:

あれだろ？ 岬波の、英語の音読女子が載せてバズったやつ。
You mean that stuff? Minami's video that went viral after the English Read-aloud Girl posted it?

